# Include .jar in my qt project

Tags: c++, qt, jar

I'm writing an application for android with qt. I use Epson BT-300 as device. Epson provided me a library to control display brightness. the library is a .jar file (i'm not familiar with java). I've try to use `QAndroidJniObject display("com.epson.moverio.btcontrol.DisplayControl")` but the linker returns me `error: undefined reference to 'QAndroidJniObject::QAndroidJniObject(char const*)'` I don't know how to insert my .jar file in my qt project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message shown it seems like you do not link against the `androidextras` module. Check out the [module documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) as it explains how to properly include the module in your app (assuming you are using `qmake`).

Generally, I would recommend you to head over to KDAB. They have a very nice tutorial series about Qt on Android. In particular, episodes [5](https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-5/), [6](https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-6/) and [7](https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-7/) might be of interest for you.